# How to run, and access http://localhost/TutorialApp success?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, sencha-cmd

I am reading http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/guides/tutorials/login_app.html

I see
[image]

I don't understand about http://localhost/TutorialApp

- What is command I must release before access link http://localhost/TutorialApp ?
- What doesn't it mean?
- What is the difference between http://localhost/TutorialApp and http://localhost:1841/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your apache running locally and you create the tutorial app at the root of your server, you will be able to access through: `http://localhost/TutorialApp`.

If you don't have your apache server running locally, you can run `sencha app watch` and Sencha Cmd will create an instance for you that can be accessed through `http://localhost:1841`